# How do I upgrade an existing Cloud Service Project to use Azure SDK 3.0?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk

I'm migrating from VS2015 to VS2017, and updating a repo's solutions to be able to be compatible with VS2017. In the process, I'm also updating the Azure SDK version from 2.7 to 3.0.

I'm setting up a fresh dev environment, and installed Azure SDK 3.0 via VS2017's [Azure development workload](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/visual-studio-workloads/).

When I opened the solution file in the repo, I got one notice per cloud service project that its Microsoft Azure Tools version was getting upgraded from 2.7 to 2.9...

[image: upgrade prompt]

...and the `ProductVersion` tag in the corresponding .csproj files was updated from 2.7 to 2.9.

Questions:

- Why wasn't this updated to 3.0?
- Is there anyway for me to update it
  to 3.0 without manually editing the csproj file? I don't see an
  option to do so in Properties when I right click the cloud service
  projects in Solution Explorer.
- Is there some reason I shouldn't be
  doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Microsoft Azure Tools - v2.9" mentioned in your screenshot is just a little misleading.

Underlying reason is that Microsoft hasn't really changed the version number of most components as part of 3.0 SDK release. Even the binaries get installed in the same folder as 2.9.

Good news is that you don't need to do anything special apart from converting the project to target latest version, which you're already getting prompted for.

**So once you do convert your project as per the prompt, you're essentially working with SDK 3.0, even though version string says v2.9, because as the links explain, most of the components haven't changed major version number as part of SDK 3.0 version (when comparing with 2.9)**

Here are some of the links which talk about this -

[Azure SDK for .NET 3.0 Release Summary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-sdk-dotnet-release-notes-3-0)

> No breaking changes to the Azure SDK 3.0 have been introduced in this
>   release. There is also no upgrade process needed to leverage this SDK
>   with existing Cloud Service projects. To allow use of the Azure SDK
>   3.0 without requiring an upgrade process, Azure SDK 3.0 installs to the same directories as Azure SDK 2.9. Most the components did not
>   change the major version from 2.9 but instead just updated the build
>   number.

[Visual Studio 2017 latest installer does not install Azure SDK 3.0](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/33700/visual-studio-2017-latest-installer-does-not-insta.html)

In this link look at the response from Devin Breshears - MSFT
[image]

[Azure 3.0 SDK Install Weirdness](https://nerdymishka.com/blog/azure-3-0-sdk-install-weirdness/)
An independent blog talking about the same issue.

Comment: @BobbyA, were you able to upgrade? or still having issues with this one?

Comment: Yup. It's kinda crazy that the ProductVersion tags in the csproj files still read 2.9, but then again, this is Microsoft.